# Play Video Echo Show

Tags: node.js, video, alexa-skills-kit, amazon-echo-show

I'm creating an Echo Show skill that plays a specific video on command. I created an intent that contains a speak and playVideo command. However, when the specific intent is prompted, although Alexa executes the speak command, the video never plays. Instead, the skill just ends with no error reports.

Strangely, when I moved the if/else block to my start function, the video played normally. As far as I understand, the video is skipped over because it is in an intent. Is there something that I'm missing/failing to enable because the videoPlay command is in an intent?

This is my intent:

```
'PlayVideoA'() {
        new Logger(__filename, 'PlayVideoA');
        if (this.event.context.System.device.supportedInterfaces.VideoApp) {
            this.response.playVideo(LINK);
            const message = 'A video should have played';
            this.response.speak(message);
            this.emit(':responseReady');
        } else {
            this.response.speak("The video cannot be played on your device. " +
            "To watch this video, try launching the skill from your echo show device.");
            this.emit(':responseReady');
        }  
    }
```